# Lost iPad - Tracking (no cellular plan)

Tags: ipad, find-my-iphone

I got my iPad stolen out of my car after a break-in last week.
I do have Find My on there, but I only use WiFi and haven’t had cellular data on there.

Is it possible to add cellular data without the iPad, so I can track it?

If not, does anyone have any advice on how I might be able to track it?

I’ve already reported it stolen in my city.

Answer (score 0):

#### Cellular service is provisioned on the physical device

> Is it possible to add cellular data without the iPad, so I can track it?

Assuming your device is cellular capable, you unfortunately cannot set up cellular service after the fact.  You need physical access to the device to either...

- install a SIM card and provision service
- provision an eSIM and your cell service

Apple's Support Document [Set up cellular service on iPad (Wi-Fi + Cellular models)](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/set-up-cellular-service-ipad9940e098/ipados) goes into details regarding this.

#### Use Find My to track your device

> If not, does anyone have any advice on how I might be able to track it?

If you haven't done so already, turn on Find My.  Even if you don't have cellular service, the Find My network is an anonymous network of nearby Apple devices.  As long as your device is in proximity to another Apple device (it doesn't have to be yours), it can be detected.

From the Support Document [Use the Find My app to locate a missing device or item](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210515):

> If you turn on Find My network, you can locate your device or item even if it's not connected to a Wi-Fi or cellular network. The Find My network is an encrypted anonymous network of hundreds of millions of Apple devices that can help you locate your device or item.

#### Next actions to take...

Finally, [Apple provides an excellent checklist of what do to in case you lose your device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201472)

The most important steps to take are as follows:

- Locate it on a map
- Mark lost to remotely lock it
- Report the loss to law enforcement
- Remote wipe to secure your personal data