# Why could FindMy not detect a charged Airpod

Tags: find-my-iphone, find-my-mac, find-my

My Airpod is fully charged I'm not sure where I left it. I couldn't find the location using FindMy.

Any ideas what should I be doing?

How close should I be to the Airpod to find it?

[image]

Comment: "Fully charged" is highly subjective.  This is what was detected the last time it connected.  For Find My to work you just need to be near *any* Apple device so its location just sent to the owner.  If the battery is dead, you're not going to find it.

Comment: @Allan - I'm wondering all these devices atleast should show .. last location right .. I mean for apple watch or iphones or Airpod.. why is it not showing ?

Comment: If it's not holding a charge long enough to check in with the Apple network, you're not going to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Find My is an excellent tool, but like everything else, it's not perfect.

> My Airpod is fully charged I'm not sure where I left it.

Unfortunately, we can't know this.  Battery charging levels deplete over time and [a general life expectancy for accessories like this is 3-5 years](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342147/119271).  You may believe the battery is fully charged, however, it simply won't hold a good charge because it's 7 years old (at the time of this writing).

While Airpods aren't discrete devices (like phones or tablets) that can connect to a network and update its location services, they do that the ability to check in to the "mothership" using the [Find My network](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/463556/119271)
Airpods need to connect to other Apple devices to update it's location.

While that feature is very innovative, if your AirPod never comes into proximity of another Apple device (nor do they have the charge to complete the process), you're not going to be able to find their geolocation.